# I don't get what I am doing wrong with this Thévenin question

Tags: resistance, thevenin

[image: Problem]

I understand that the Thévenin voltage is zero because there are only dependent sources, but finding the Thévenin resistance doesn't seem to work.

My work for finding the Thévenin resistance is below. I attached a 1 V power supply and used the three nodes, but I can't seem to get equations that allow me to find the value of at least of the variables. 3 variables, 3 equations.

[image: Work to try and find the Thévenin resistance]

Comment: Did you crop 'B' off the bottom right of the diagram?

Comment: Yeah B was cropped off in the diagram on the site I saw it on

Comment: @Otto367 It is a requirement of this site that material (images or text) from other sources **MUST** be attributed. In this case the url of the site re which you said "Yeah B was cropped off in the diagram on the site I saw it on" ||We did mot make this rule, it's set by the site owners to avoid plagiarism claims and legal consequences. SO, again, we didn't make the rule, we just enforce it. Please add a link to the source of the diagram.

Comment: @Otto367 You have revisited the site since I asked you to add a source for the diagram. If you do not do so the question will, necessarily, be closed. Which would be a shame, as periblepsis has put effort into helping you. Please add the required citation.

Comment: @Otto367 Sadly, your question has been closed as you were told would happen if you did not add am mage source. This is a site requirement which we have no control over - and reflects standard copyright practice all over the western world. || If you add a valid link the question can be reopened.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of plagiarism and failing to provide a link when requested after several subsequent visits to the site.

Comment: **NOTE** the close reasons are made up by the system and are rubbish. Actual reason is given above.

Answer (score 1):

#### number parts, please

If and when available (desktop use), please use the schematic editor. It numbers parts. Here's the schematic from your notebook (glad to see you using one!):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSxNdG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

#### schematic simplification

We know that \$V_3=V_a\$ here but it looks a bit messy with all those wires. So let's get rid of them:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgboLE.png)</sup>

\$V_2\$ is gone. Nice.

#### without any stimulus

However, as it stands the best solution would be to set all the voltages to zero. As you correctly noted:

> I understand that the Thévenin voltage is zero because there are only
> dependent sources

#### adding a stimulus

To handle this, inject \$1\:\text{A}\$ into node \$V_3\$ to see how it responds. The developed KCL ***must*** include this injected current. *(The use of \$1\:\text{A}\$  is just to simplify the result. Any non-zero current would work as well.)*

The KCL equations are then:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_1}{R_2}+\frac{V_1}{R_5}&=\frac{2\cdot\left(V_3-V_1\right)}{R_2}+\frac{V_3}{R_5}
\\\\
\frac{V_3}{R_3}+\frac{V_3}{R_4}+\frac{V_3}{R_5}&=\frac{2\cdot\left(V_3-V_1\right)}{R_3}+\frac{V_1}{R_5}+1\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$

Using SymPy (Python and SageMath):

```
e1 = Eq( v1/r1 + v1/r2 + v1/r5, 2*(v3-v1)/r2 + v3/r5 )       # KCL for V1
e3 = Eq( v3/r3 + v3/r4 + v3/r5, 2*(v3-v1)/r3 + v1/r5 + i1 )  # KCL for V3
for i,j in solve([e1,e3],[v1,v3]).items():i,j.subs({r1:1,r2:2,r3:1,r4:2,r5:1,i1:1})
(v1, 8/15)
(v3, 14/15)
```

And done. We find that \$V_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{V_3}{1\:\text{A}}=\frac{14}{15}\:\Omega\$.

You can keep \$V_2\$, of course. In this case,

```
e1 = Eq( v1/r1 + v1/r2 + v1/r5, v2/r2 + v3/r5 )       # KCL for V1
e2 = Eq( v2, 2*(v3-v1) )                              # Equiv. for V2
e3 = Eq( v3/r3 + v3/r4 + v3/r5, v2/r3 + v1/r5 + i1 )  # KCL for V3
for i,j in solve([e1,e2,e3],[v1,v2,v3]).items():i,j.subs({r1:1,r2:2,r3:1,r4:2,r5:1,i1:1})
(v1, 8/15)
(v2, 4/5)
(v3, 14/15)
```

A little more information. But no actual change.

#### verification

It never hurts to verify:

[image]

#### final notes

There's no necessary need to inject \$1\:\text{A}\$. Any value is fine. Here, I inject \$25\:\text{mA}\$, instead:

```
e1 = Eq( v1/r1 + v1/r2 + v1/r5, v2/r2 + v3/r5 )       # KCL for V1
e2 = Eq( v2, 2*(v3-v1) )                              # Equiv. for V2
e3 = Eq( v3/r3 + v3/r4 + v3/r5, v2/r3 + v1/r5 + i1 )  # KCL for V3
for i,j in solve([e1,e2,e3],[v1,v2,v3]).items():i,(j/i1).subs({r1:1,r2:2,r3:1,r4:2,r5:1,i1:0.025})
(v1, 0.533333333333333)
(v2, 0.800000000000000)
(v3, 0.933333333333333)
```

The result is the same. The point is that something needs to be injected so that you can work out (from the injection) what the Thevenin resistance is.

The basic idea remains.